# Returning values from a function

Tags: python, pandas

This is a simple python question but am getting frustrated with it...

I am trying to choose randomly selected days for three prices series as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.data as web
import random

symbls = ['SPX','TLT','MSFT']
y = web.get_data_yahoo(symbls, start='2007-01-01')
x = y['Adj Close']

def choose_days(df, pct):
    n = len(df)
    n1 = int(round(pct*n))
    ss = df.iloc[sorted(random.sample(range(0,n-1),k=n1))]
    ss

ll = choose_days(x,0.01)

print ll
```

This does not produce the output I was hoping for. I was hoping for a dataframe to be the output with 1% of the days. I'm not too sure which bit i need to correct. I think it relates to the function but not sure how...

Comment: You're missing a return there: `return ss`

Comment: Ah knew it was simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to return something it needs a `return`. Change `ss` to `return ss`

http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions